# Get Account and Account Owner User map

Tags: territory-management

I need to get the Account owners. In our case they are the users assigned to territories.

Below is my approach.

1. Query the Accounts
2. Query the AccountShare object for above accounts
   select Id, AccountId, UserOrGroupId, RowCause from AccountShare 
       where AccountId IN :accounts and RowCause In ('TerritoryManual','Territory')
3. Query Group object based on UserOrGroupId from above query result
   select Id, RelatedId from Group where Id IN AccountShare.RelatedId
4. Query UserTerritory based on the territoryId result form above query
   select Id, UserId, TerritoryId from UserTerritory where TerritoryId IN :Group.TerritoryId

My problem is I don't know how to get the mapping between Account and UserId.

Also tried combining AccountShare and Group query in single SOQL but it's not working.(UserOrGroupId is a foreign key in AccessShare object but not sure how to traverse the relationship)

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a series of maps, one at each step, to create the linkage.  First a map of accounted to groupid - Map.  The one item that could be tricky would be the user to group mapping.  Since more than one user could be in the group, the final map might need to be a list map - Map>